# what value an array gets when intiallized

Tags: c, arrays

In C, when I declare an array:

```
char MyArray[100] = { 0 };
```

What is the value inserted into the array's elements?

Is it possible to fill it with `NULL`s?

Comment: @Bathsheba I wonder that too. Maybe someone came from a language in which  `null` denotes other things..

Comment: Why would you like to fill it with NULL values? NULL is a pointer value (or rather the absence of a value).

Comment: I didn't downvoted anyone :O
I created a list and filled it partially. I want a loop to break when it gets to the unfilled part, and with `""` or `\0` it wont work..

Comment: @TzahiLeh - a list ? Do mean an array? If you want a loop that breaks, why not describe that in the question instead of doing it in a comment?

Comment: @4386427 because this problem I want to solve by myself ;)
Yes, I meant array..

Comment: There's thousands of very similar questions regarding array initialization on SO.

Comment: @TzahiLeh - Great that you want to solve that part yourself. I still don't get what you mean by "filled partially" - the array is completely filled with zeros.

Comment: @4386427 filled partially, manually, with values (which are not zeros)

Comment: @TzahiLeh - `char MyArray[100] = { 1, 2, 3 };` will put 1, 2, 3 as the first three elements in the array and the remaining 97 will be 0 (zero). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: `NULL` is a pointer.  and the array is `char`, not `char*`.  the posted code will fill the array with all 0x00 however, this is due to an implicit conversion done by the compiler.  Since the elements of the array a `char` the init value should also be `char`.  Suggest the init value be the character: `\0' rather than the integer 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, all elements will be initialized with null character `'\0'`.

C11-§6.7.9/21:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or **fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.

and paragraph 10 says that

> [...] If an object that has **static** or thread **storage duration** is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>   — if it has [arithmetic type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types), it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>   — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>   — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

---

> Is it possible to fill it with NULLs?

`NULL` is a macro which is used for null pointers and not for null characters.

Comment: "static storage duration" is the important part. For pointers, that means the null pointer value.

Comment: Why the downvote? This looks comprehensive, and correct, to me.

Comment: An explanation for downvote would help me to figure out what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba; That ghost downvoted every answer. May be he is confused.

Answer (score 3):

In the declaration

```
char MyArray[100] = { 0 };
```

all elements are initialized to zero. Filling it with NULL:s makes no real sense, however you can use the character constant `'\0'` if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

In `C` the preprocessor macro `NULL` is defined (by several headers, including `<stdio.h>` and `<stddef.h>`) as a null pointer constant, typically `0` or `((void *)0)`.

So basically you can only initialize values to `0` (or `\0` for `char`) which your code is doing for the entire array, `NULL` has a different purpose - its not the same as `null` in other languages like C# or Java.

Even if you wrote:

```
char MyArray[100] = { 65 };
```

The remaining elements will be initialized to `0` by the Compiler.

[NULL should be used only as a pointer constant](http://c-faq.com/null/nullor0.html)

Answer (score 3):

Compiler set default value for omitted array elements. The compiler that reserves the 100 **zero bytes** in the data segement of the program.

Comment: Not 100 bytes... 100*sizeof(int) bytes!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: U wot? sizeof(char) is 1

Comment: @Jean sizeof char 1 byte, sizeof int 4 byte, So depend on that array is a 100 char elements. So char array size is 100bytes.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, all the memory attributable to the array is set to `\0`.

This is true in general with the exception of pointers which are initialised to the null pointer value (which *might* be 0 but the C standard does not insist on that).

Note that the `NULL` of C does not denote a `null` reference value as it does in other languages such as Java.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized all elements of your array with the value 0, this is what `= { 0 }` stands for in an initialization expression.

Filling with `NULL` is non-sense as `NULL` is value defined for pointers and your array is an array of `char`s not pointer to something.

Maybe what you would like is to set the value to something that would mean *not defined yet*, but this does not exists in C. Every variable, at the time, it is defined, as a value. `NULL` doesn't mean *no value*, but does not point to something; but it is a value!

Comment: array of `int`? array of `char`, isn't it